# Datepicker event change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using two datepicker and I want it to trigger only when a date inside the calendar is clicked. I have written an input change so it is getting triggered for the following events:

```
'start_date' : $('#start_date').val(),
'end_date' : $('#end_date').val()
```

and

```
$('#start_date').val(div_data[i].start_date);
$('#end_date').val(div_data[i].end_date);
```

This is the datepicker:

```
  $('.filter_date').datepicker().on("input change", function (e) {
    var form_data = [];
    form_data = rank_data()
    if (form_data.length != 0){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/visual/plot',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'form_data': JSON.stringify(form_data)},
        success: function(data){
          if (data != false){

          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I want to call this ajax only on clicking inside the datepicker calendar is there any way?

Comment: Can you let us know exactly which datepicker plugin you are using of the myriad options.

Comment: I am using bootstrap datepicker : https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Look at all the `script src=` in your HTML - they'll be a jquery.n.n.n.js and maybe bootstrap.js or jquery-ui.js or boostrap-datepicker.js

Comment: I have updated my comment @freedomn-m I am using the bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: datepicker UX is designed to allow you to enter the date via the inbox - eg if you copy a date from somewhere it's very bad design to then have to do half a dozen clicks rather than just paste.  But if that's really what you want: make the input readonly so that it can't be changed other than via the picker, [enable readonly](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#enableonreadonly) then listen for the [changeDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate) event.

Comment: changing to readonly won't help because the user needs to select start date before 10 years so if we change to readonly the user has to go through the years manually right ? It won't be helpful in my case.

Comment: In which case you'll need to define what your case *actually is*.  You say you want it *"only on clicking"* and you already have it on `input change` - so what's it doing that you don't want / not doing that you do want right now?

Comment: I don't want that trigger to happen and this is my alternate idea just to call this ajax only when clicking or the date or closing it ?